# Read all files line by line in a directory and do a command on them

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, directory

I am trying to make a script that will allow me to read all files in a directory line by line while doing a command to a specific column of these files.  The files that I am dealing with are .txt files that have values that are separated by commas.  I am able to execute the code with a single file by inputting the text file to the script and then outputting the values but not with multiple files, which is my goal.  I would like the files to be read in the order they are in in the directory.  Here is what I have so far.

```
directory=$(/dos2unix/*.txt)
file=$(*.txt")
IFS=","
for "$file" in "$directory";
do
    while read -ra line;
    do
            if [ "${line[1]}" != "" ]; then
                echo -n "${line[*]}, Hash Value:"; echo "${line[1]}" | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //'
            else
                if [ "${line[1]}" == "" ]; then
                    echo "${line[*]}, Hash Value:None";
                fi
            fi
    done
done
```

Some of the errors that I am getting are:

```
$ ./orange2.sh
/dos2unix/test1.txt: line 1: hello: command not found
/dos2unix/test1.txt: line 2: goodbye: command not found
/dos2unix/test1.txt: line 4: last: command not found
./orange2.sh: line 28: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./orange2.sh: line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Any tips, suggestions, or examples?

Thanks all

## UPDATE

I am also looking to copy all of the files eventually to contain the command that you see in the first if statement so I would like to a.) keep my files separate and b.) create a copy that will contain the updated value.

Comment: google for `find -type f -execdir cmd {} \;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the file names in a variable, use `array=(a b c)` syntax to create an array. There's no dollar sign. Then loop over the array with `for item in "${array[@]}"`.

To read from a file with a `while read` loop, use `while read; do ...; done < "$file"`. It's odd-looking, but the file is redirected into the loop as a whole.

```
files=(/dos2unix/*.txt)

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    while IFS=',' read -ra line; do
        ...
    done < "$file"
done
```

Another way is to use `cat` to concatenate all the files together, which lets you get rid of the outer `for` loop.

```bsh
cat /dos2unix/*.txt | while IFS=',' read -ra line; do
    ...
done
```

Comment: I like where you are going with the first example and it looks like it should work but when I actually run the script, it takes me to the next line to input text as if I were not asking for a file.  I'd like to not concat the files because somewhere down the line we would like to make copies of the files keeping all files separated.  Any idea why it's not reading the files and is asking for text?

Comment: @Beardy `cat` doesn't modify the files, it just prints them one after the other to stdout.

Comment: right but if I were to want to copy the files such as file1.txt to file1-copy.txt then I would probably not want to use cat.  I would like to essentially read all files but read one by one, copying it's contents with the updated command that I would run on a specific column.  The copy would contain the update. Does that make sense?